# Problema ejecutando codigo c++ en Netbeans "Debugger error: During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139."

Tags: c++, netbeans

Estoy programando un sencillo código en C++ con NetBeans. El código me compila bien en NetBeans y en otros entornos(Dev C++) funciona.
Sin embargo, a la hora de correr en Netbeans me da el siguiente error:

> RUN FAILED (exit value -1.073.741.511, total time: 47ms)

Después uso el depurador y me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> Debugger error: During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.

Y no termina de ejecutarse.

El codigo es:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class cadena {
    public:
    cadena();        // Constructor por defecto
    cadena(const char *c); // Constructor desde cadena c
    cadena(int n);   // Constructor de cadena de n caracteres
    cadena(const cadena &);   // Constructor copia
    ~cadena();       // Destructor

    void Asignar(const char *dest);
    char *Leer(char *c);
    private:
    char *cad;       // Puntero a char: cadena de caracteres
};

cadena::cadena() : cad(NULL) {}

cadena::cadena(const char *c) {
    cad = new char[strlen(c)+1];// Reserva memoria para cadena
    strcpy(cad, c);             // Almacena la cadena
}

cadena::cadena(int n) {
    cad = new char[n+1]; // Reserva memoria para n caracteres
    cad[0] = 0;          // Cadena vacía
}

cadena::cadena(const cadena &Cad) {
    // Reservamos memoria para la nueva y la almacenamos
    cad = new char[strlen(Cad.cad)+1];
    // Reserva memoria para cadena
    strcpy(cad, Cad.cad);             // Almacena la cadena
}

cadena::~cadena() {
    delete[] cad;        // Libera la memoria reservada a cad
}

void cadena::Asignar(const char *dest) {
    // Eliminamos la cadena actual:
    delete[] cad;
    // Reservamos memoria para la nueva y la almacenamos
    cad = new char[strlen(dest)+1];
    // Reserva memoria para la cadena
    strcpy(cad, dest);              // Almacena la cadena
}

char *cadena::Leer(char *c) {
    strcpy(c, cad);
    return c;
}

int main() {
    cadena Cadena1("Cadena de prueba");
    cadena Cadena2(Cadena1);   // Cadena2 es copia de Cadena1
    cadena *Cadena3;           // Cadena3 es un puntero
    char c[256];

    // Modificamos Cadena1:
    Cadena1.Asignar("Otra cadena diferente");
    // Creamos Cadena3:
    Cadena3 = new cadena("Cadena de prueba nº 3");

    // Ver resultados
    cout << "Cadena 1: " << Cadena1.Leer(c) << endl;
    cout << "Cadena 2: " << Cadena2.Leer(c) << endl;
    cout << "Cadena 3: " << Cadena3->Leer(c) << endl;

    delete Cadena3;  // Destruir Cadena3.
    // Cadena1 y Cadena2 se destruyen automáticamente

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: El código está sacado de la página http://conclase.net/ por si a alguien le interesa.

Answer (score 2):

Tu programa en sí no tiene errores a la hora de compilarse / ejecutarse, por lo que tu error posiblemente se deba a una mala configuración del proyecto de netbeans. A falta de más información por tu parte la respuesta a tu problema termina aquí.

Lo que sí sucede es que tu clase `cadena` es peligrosa por definición.

Imagina que hacemos lo siguiente:

```
cadena cad1;
cadena cad2(cad1);
char c[255];

std::cout << cad1.Leer(c) << std::endl;
std::cout << cad2.Leer(c) << std::endl;
```

¿Cómo se va a comportar la función?

Bueno, si atendemos a la implementación del constructor por defecto:

```
cadena::cadena() : cad(NULL) {}
```

tendremos que el puntero `cad1.cad` apunta a 0 (nota que apuntar a 0 no implica que `*cad1.cad==0`).

Después llamamos al constructor copia para construir `cad2`:

```
cadena::cadena(const cadena &Cad) {
    // Reservamos memoria para la nueva y la almacenamos
    cad = new char[strlen(Cad.cad)+1];
    // Reserva memoria para cadena
    strcpy(cad, Cad.cad);             // Almacena la cadena
}
```

Y aquí empiezan los problemas. ¿Qué devuelve `strlen(0)`? Ya te adelanto que no tiene por qué devolver nada bueno, eso suponiendo que el programa no casque. Al final vas a hacer una reserva de memoria de tamaño indeterminado y vas a intentar hacer una copia tal que `strcpy(cad,0)`, lo cual tampoco tiene demasiada buena pinta.

Para remata la faena después imagínate que seguimos ejecutando y llegamos al método `Leer`:

```
char *cadena::Leer(char *c) {
    strcpy(c, cad);
    return c;
}

std::cout << cad1.Leer(c) << std::endl;
```

Y volvemos a repetir los problemas: `strcpy(c,0)` y `std::cout << (char*)0 << std::endl;`.

Te puedes hacer una idea de que los problemas que origina el constructor por defecto son variados. Mi propuesta es que declares el constructor por defecto como privado y no le añadas implementación, de tal forma que fuera de la clase será inaccesible (por ser privado) y dentro de la clase tampoco podrá ser invocado (puesto que no tiene implementación).

Un saludo.